# Force.com User Needs to See Leads

Tags: force.com

I have about 40 force.com users that do not have access to leads in salesforce but need to be able to view, potentially edit and add activities to leads. Upgrading their license is not an option for budget purposes.

We are toying with the ideas of:

1) Creating a Shadow Table but any edits they make to the shadow will a trigger will not be able to update the Lead because they are the running user without access to the Lead.

2) Having Leads converted to Person Accounts way earlier in the cycle which will be a nightmare for reporting.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how we could make something work based on this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

The shadow table idea might work if you have a single user with enough privileges to access the leads. Then, a scheduled class would process and apply the changes from the shadow table to the actual Lead table.

Now, I must warn you that I believe that this not legally allowed (based on the Terms of Service).

Comment: That is a really good point. We may go with option 2 to avoid any conflict.

Comment: Actually, from a *technical* perspective, as long as they're in system mode, trigger code can create/update leads even for users without that object available to them. However, it *is* a violation of the various TOS, and can result in being retroactively charged for the amount of time/number of licenses that were used this way to skirt paying full prices.